# Draw the rectangle and fill the rectangle based on (x,y) points

Tags: java, android

I was not able to figure out how to fill the drawn rectangle based on (x,y) points. Basically inside (x,y) points. There can be a array of (x,y) points.

Anyone can help on this.....

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, what library you're using for drawing and stuff like that?

Comment: Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(0x75FFFF00);
canvas.drawRect(new RectF(67, 133, 285, 345), paint);

But this will fill the whole rectangle....

But i want only those inside (x,y) points to get filled rest all should be empty.....

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectange(length, width, x, y);
r.fill(Color.yourColor);

Graphics g = getGraphics();
g.draw(r);
```

Comment: I think you have not understood the point. I will update the question again with image also.....

Comment: I create rectangle as following :
RectF(180.0, 1182.4459, 1043.9844, 1233.3003)


Suppose I have the following points. I have 7 points of (x,y).

PointF(632.812, 1207.2604)
PointF(1043.9844, 1207.2604)
PointF(1043.9844, 1182.4459)
PointF(632.812, 1182.4459)
PointF(180.0, 1233.3003)
PointF(528.13995, 1233.3003)
PointF(528.13995, 1208.4858)

I want to fill the created rectangle with respect to above 7 PointF of (x,y). Plz find the below image

I hope you all got my question now.....